# Knockout JS and executing $.ajax upon textInput change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I have a dynamically generated table based on what data is retrieved from database so my list of objects that come from database look like this:

```
public string Account { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public decimal A2Year { get; set; }
public decimal A1Year { get; set; }
public decimal B1Year { get; set; }
public decimal Current { get; set; }
public decimal Proposed { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<CustomerInfo> UserSalaries { get; set; }
```

I retrieve this data using $.ajax get function and because it is a list I generate table in the following way:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: accountData">
    <tr class="dept-row" role="row">
        <td><span data-bind="text: Description"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Account"></span></td>
        <td class="center-text"><a data-bind="click: function(){ $parent.showNoteDialog(Account)}"></a></td>
        <td class="align-right"><span data-bind="text: A2Year"></span></td>
        <td class="align-right"><span data-bind="text: B1Year"></span></td>
        <td class="align-right"><span data-bind="text: A1Year"></span></td>
        <td class="align-right"><span data-bind="text: Current"></span></td>
        <td><input class="align-right dollar-amount" data-bind="textInput: Proposed" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Table is generated properly and in my view model I only have following line:

```
self.accountData = ko.observableArray();
```

What I am trying to accomplish and I am new to KnockoutJS is when "Proposed" input value changes, I would like to call $.ajax function to save this value into the database. I have read and tried with binding "hasFocus" so I can call ajax upon leaving field, but I was not able to generate table if I add hasFocus binding because then all input fields have exactly same bindings. Any suggestions how to achieve this? Should proposed values be in its own observable array or tracking entire list of object is good enough? Ultimate question is how would I call ajax function to save data upon data is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, you have these requirements:

1. You want the ajax function to be called when the value of `Proposed` changes.
2. You want the ajax function to be called when the value changes AND only when `Proposed`'s input field has lost focus.

Correct?

In that case, you need to make these changes:

1. Change the data-binding of `Proposed` from 'textInput' to 'value', as in `data-bind="value: Proposed"`.
2. The binding will work only when `Proposed` itself is an observable. In fact, all your values need to be observables **IF** they are going to be change and you need to reflect those changes in the UI dynamically. You can use observables inside observables arrays.
3. To call the ajax function whenever the value of `Proposed` changes, you need to 'subscribe' to it, so that you can listen to its changes.

The basic way - use the `subscribe` function:

```
self.Proposed.subscribe(function(newValue){
    //call ajax
});
```

The advanced, more structured way - use [extenders](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html).

Comment: I know about value binding but according to their documentation `textInput` should be used over `value` binding (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html). I know about subscribers but this is in case I know number of input fields and I have observable for each. Am I missing something? Can I use subscriber for observable array to see when one value of observable changes?

Comment: You want the ajax call to happen after leaving the field and only if the data changes right? Then you need value binding. textInput responds even before you leave the field. Subscriber for observable array works when you add or delete elements from the array, not when you modify one of the elements. And ideally you SHOULD have observables for all input fields... otherwise why even use knockout?

Comment: that is correct I should have observable for each element in array, this is the piece that I am not sure how to accomplish.

Comment: You can either write them manually or use the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).

Comment: @zuboje if you want, you can ask a new question on using observables inside observable arrays and using the mapping plugin.